# Как отметить роль в discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я хочу чтобы в сообщении бот отмечал @YouTube. Я поискал в интернете так и не нашёл, поэтому спрашиваю здесь       :)

Как отметить роль в discord.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

эм.. ну <@&idrole> в коде вписываешь и пингует

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

```
await ctx.send(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id='role_id').mention)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]